# I want to have the same Table Dropdown value

Tags: javascript, dropdown

[image]

```
var songsRef = firebase.database().ref('/KTV-Bar/' + loggeduser + '/Reservations/');


songsRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

    mRetrieveSongs = snapshot.val();
    $("#dataTables").append(
     "<tr data-id='" + snapshot.key + "'>"
       + "<td>" + mRetrieveSongs.playlistkey + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + mRetrieveSongs.username + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + mRetrieveSongs.numberofhours + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + mRetrieveSongs.dates + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + snapshot.key + "</td>"
         // +"<td id=room>"+"</td>"
       + "<td id=room>" + '<select id="selectRoom"></select>' + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + mRetrieveSongs.capacity + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + '<input type="button" value="Accept" id = "accept" onclick="writeUserData(this)" ">'
       + ' <input type="button" value="Decline" id = "decline" onclick="myFunctionDecline(this)" ">'
       + "<td>" + '<th> </th>">'
       + "</td>"
   + "</tr>"

   )

});

var roomRef = firebase.database().ref('/KTV-Bar/' + loggeduser + '/Room');
roomRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

    mRetrieveRooms = snapshot.val();
    rooms = mRetrieveRooms.room;


    var select = document.getElementById("selectRoom");
    for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        var opt = rooms[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }

});
```

I want to have the same data of my dropdowns in each row of the table. I populated my dropdowns from my firebase data, but it only populated the first row dropdown of the table.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `select` box with a common class rather than same IDs? Multiple elements with same IDs is not valid HTML.

Comment: Whatever options you get from firebase data keep it in a variable. Now, append this variables as `options` to other dropdowns

Comment: @KalpeshSingh it doesnt work. Still, only the first row gets populated

Comment: @Varun . I haven't tried that yet . how to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your replys . I appreciate it

Comment: @Earvin Does my answer below help you?

Comment: @KalpeshSingh no. still, only the first row dropdown of the table is populated bay the data..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are appending options dynamically. You can take advantage of my code to generate desire output.

```js
var options = ["Make", "America", "Great", "Again"];

var firstDropdown = document.getElementById('first');
var secondDropdown = document.getElementById('second');

appendOptions(firstDropdown, options);

appendOptions(secondDropdown, options);

function appendOptions(elem, options) {
  options.forEach(function(value) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = value;
    elem.appendChild(option);
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="first">
</select>

<select id="second">
</select>
```